# Static Global variable in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, static, linker, global-variables

```
// in ClassA.h  
static NSString *globalStr = @"HelloWorld";

@interface ClassA  
    ...  
@end

// in ClassB.h  
#include "ClassA.h"

// in ClassB.m  
...  
NSLog(@"The global string: %@", globalStr);
...
```

In C++, "static" should mean the variable or function has a internal linkage.
But it is used to share the variable in this case, error will occur without the static keyword.

I'm confused, could someone tell me the concept behind?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`static` means exactly the same thing in Objective-C that in means in C - it has internal linkage and static storage duration.  You get an error without the `static` in this case because you will have a duplicate symbol `globalStr` in each object whose source code included `ClassA.h`.  You're not *sharing* anything - you're getting a new copy of `globalStr` for each compilation unit.

Don't put object definitions in your headers and you'll be better off.  If you want a single global string, you need to put

```
extern NSString *globalStr;
```

In `ClassA.h`, and define it in *exactly one* implementation file as:

```
NSString *globalStr = @"HelloWorld";
```

Comment: It helps to remember that headers are *literally copied* into the file they're included in. You're not "sharing" the variable with other files that import the header — the header is causing all those files to each contain the declaration `static NSString *globalStr = @"HelloWorld"`.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't really know why there is a "duplicate symbol". Could you explain more, thanks again.