# Is there a difference between a global and a static global?

Tags: objective-c, static, global-variables

In Objective C (if that matters) is there a difference between these two statements?  And if so, what?

Statement 1:

```
std::map<id, id> foo;
```

Statement 2:

```
static std::map<id, id> sFoo;
```

Note that these are both globals that would be declared in the .mm at file scope.

Comment: Is that C++/Objective-C++, rather than Objective-C?

Comment: This has been asked before, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055641/static-global-variable-in-obj-c - note that use of `static` outside of a class or function means the same thing (internal linkage) in C, C++, Objective-C, and Objective-C++.

Comment: I honestly don't know the difference between the two (ObjC vs ObjC++).

Comment: Objective-C adds a reflective object-oriented runtime with semantics a lot like Smalltalk to C. Objective-C++ adds the same things to C++. std:map is part of the Standard Template Library, a set of C++ templates, so you're in Objective-C++ territory. Whereas the ObjC features overwhelmingly add to C, with C++ there's a lot of overlap so a lot of people just don't bother with C++. E.g. they'd use an NSDictionary or NSMapTable to achieve what you're doing with a std::map, with the advantage that the built-in mechanisms for testing equality rather than identity will just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static`, in this context, means that the variable is visible only within the current file, but is visible everywhere in that file. So no: a true global variable would be visible everywhere.